# Add MediaElement.js Event Listener After Creation

Tags: javascript, mediaelement.js

Is there a way to add an event listener to a MediaElementPlayer object after it's initialized? I would like to add listeners incrementally, as needed, instead of re-creating the player each time I need to add a new listener. For example:

```
var mejsplayer = new MediaElementPlayer($("#mejsplayer"), mejsOptions);

// Keep track of added event listeners
var addedListeners = {};
function addEventListener(eventType, func) {
    if (addedListeners[eventType]) return;
    console.log("Adding listener " + eventType);
    addedListeners[eventType] = func;
    mejsplayer.addEventListener(eventType, func, false);
};
```

If that's not possible I'd like some feedback on if it really is such a bad thing to re-create the player object each time, setting the listeners with the `mejsOptions.success(mediaElement, domObject)` function.

Answer (score 0):

As said on your [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26171989/access-mediaelement-js-player-attributes/26172568#26172568) about accessing the MeJS properties, you can use the DOM element to achieve this:

```
$('#mejsplayer').bind('playing', function(e) { 
   console.log('bind - playing');
});

var player = document.getElementById('mejsplayer'); 
player.addEventListener('playing', function(e) {
   console.log('addEventListener - playing');
});
```

Comment: Thanks for both of your answers. This one didn't work for me - as I commented in the other question I can't get the DOM listeners to function correctly and I don't think they would work for fallbacks. I'm still re-creating the mejsplayer each time currently.