# Access MediaElement.js Player Attributes

Tags: javascript, mediaelement.js

I need to access the properties of a `MediaElementPlayer` object, how can I do this? The website mentions you can access properties like `currentTime` and `paused` from the `MediaElement` object, but doesn't mention `MediaElementPlayer`. An example of what I'd like to do:

```
var mejsplayer = new MediaElementPlayer($("#myplayer"), mejsOptions);

setInterval(debug, 1000);
function debug() {
    console.log("Duration is " + mejsplayer.duration);
    console.log("Current time is " + mejsplayer.currentTime);
    console.log("Volume is " + mejsplayer.volume);
    ....
};
```

The above code reports that all of these variables are undefined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a long time of working with MEJS I finally found the answer to this question. The MediaElementPlayer object encapsulates the MediaElement object, which can be accessed like this:

```
var mejsplayer = new MediaElementPlayer($("#myplayer"), mejsOptions);

setInterval(debug, 1000);
function debug() {
    console.log("Duration is " + mejsplayer.media.duration);
    console.log("Current time is " + mejsplayer.media.currentTime);
    console.log("Volume is " + mejsplayer.media.volume);
    ....
};
```

Answer (score 3):

**EDIT**

If you want to access the properties of the player you should get the DOM object. MediaElement is just some sort of extension of the  element so it still uses the DOM object. So try this:

```
new MediaElementPlayer($("#myplayer"), /*mejsOptions*/);
var player = document.getElementById('myplayer'); 
console.log(player.duration());
```

---

It is recommended to do this using the events provided, for instance:

```
<video id="player1" width="320" height="240" poster="poster.jpg" controls="controls" preload="none">
    <!-- MP4 for Safari, IE9, iPhone, iPad, Android, and Windows Phone 7 -->
    <source type="video/mp4" src="http://mediaelementjs.com/media/echo-hereweare.mp4" />
</video>

player = new MediaElementPlayer('#player1',{
    success: function (mediaElement, domObject, player) {
        mediaElement.addEventListener('timeupdate', function(e) {
            console.log("Duration is " + mediaElement.duration);
            console.log("Current time is " + mediaElement.currentTime);
            console.log("Volume is " + mediaElement.volume);
        });
    }
});
```

you can try it [here on jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mdu1oeor/3/)

Comment: +1 for the original answer, I was not able to access the DOM element as in the edited answer. Also I don't think that would work if the player was using the Flash or Silverlight fallback. It's unfortunate you can't access the properties directly!

Comment: That's right, using the dom object you can't access the fallbacks, you can only get the HTML5 genuine properties / methods